# SP - When click buttonToExcell page stay blocking

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, excel, gridview

My problem is, where i click a button for export in excel, all buttons in my page not working, when refresh everything is okay.

**This is my code for btn to excel:**

```
oid btnToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filename = String.Format("Results_{0}_{1}.xls", DateTime.Today.Month.ToString(), DateTime.Today.Year.ToString());
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableRef.Page.Title)) filename = tableRef.Page.Title + ".xls";

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

    System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();

    tableRef.Parent.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Controls.Add(tableRef);

    tableResult.Parent.Controls.Add(form);
    form.Controls.Add(tableResult);

    form.RenderControl(htmlWriter);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" />");
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of security setting of SharePoint.[Source](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/02/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-user-control-webpart.html)

All you've to do is: add the OnClientClick to the button's event,

```
_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;


<asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="btnExportToExcel_Click" OnClientClick="_spFormOnSubmitCalled = false;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;" />
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: This is working! :)